# How can I find out the installation directory of the running program in Go?

Tags: go

How can I write a `demo.go` program that prints the installation path of `demo.exe`?

```
D:\>go build demo.go
```

`demo.exe` is in `D:\`. After moving `demo.exe` to `C:\Windows`,then under the `D:\` path(it is Not in the `C:\Windows`) running `demo.exe` should print `C:\Windows`.

below picture showing than is not working for this case(because demo.exe always get its current execute path,NOT its really path) . That just tells you the current execute directory, not the directory containing the file
https://github.com/axgle/go/blob/master/may_app_path_bug.jpg

**Update: window/linux solution is here** https://github.com/axgle/app

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    path, err := filepath.Abs(os.Args[0])
    if err != nil { panic(err) }
    fmt.Println(path)
}
```

Learn more by reading about [`os.Args`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#variables) and [`filepath.Abs`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Abs).

Comment: thanks,but it's not..
mv your ./app to /some/bin/app
then run your app in the current path
should get "/some/bin/" NOT your current path

Comment: That's what it does, I believe. Please explain in more details what you do, what you get, and what you expect.

Comment: Do you try your code?I go build your demo.go code  `C:\demo.exe` get `c:\demo.exe`, then mv `c:\demo.exe` to `c:\windows`,run demo,it still get `c:\demo.exe`.===what I want to do is "app can read or write it self's path resource,such as txt file,image etc,but need to know the app's installation path,Not your current path"

Comment: Sure I did. Not on Windows, but that should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

One may try to start from e.g.:

```
package main

import "os"

func main() {
        println(os.Args[0])
}
```

---

```
$ go run main.go
/tmp/go-build135649844/command-line-arguments/_obj/a.out
$
```

(Tested on Linux only, but the os package should be cross platform where/if possible)

Comment: thanks,but it's not..
mv your ./app to /some/bin/app
then run your app in the current path
should get "/some/bin/" NOT your current path

shortly: app always get its self path(dir)
like:
vb :  app.path
php: "\_\_FILE\_\_"
not like C's "\_\_FILE\_\_"

Comment: Cannot verify that on Windows, but it doesn't make sense to me.  os.Args[0] should contain path-to-binary on all platforms, though it is not necessarily an absolute path.